# How to define hash (JSON or object) in Fluentd configuration?

Tags: logging, devops, fluentd

I have a problem with formatting labels for Google Cloud plugin for Fluentd. I want to set `logging.googleapis.com/labels` field with my own labels. That's what [Google Cloud plugin documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#special-fields) says about this field:

> The value of this field should be a structured record.

[Fluentd documentation](https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/config-file#supported-data-types-for-values) mentions that there is a `hash` data type:

> `hash`: the field is parsed as a JSON object. It also supports the shorthand syntax. These are the same values:
>
> - normal: `{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}`
> - shorthand: `key1:value1,key2:value2`

So, I tried this (quotes + braces):

```
<filter app.**>
  @type record_transformer

  renew_record true

  <record>
    severity ${record["severity"]}
    message ${record["message"]}
    logging.googleapis.com/trace ${record["trace"]}
    logging.googleapis.com/spanId ${record["spanId"]}
    logging.googleapis.com/labels {
      "kubernetes-host": "${record.dig("kubernetes", "host")}",
      "kubernetes-pod-name": "${record.dig("kubernetes", "pod_name")}",
      "kubernetes-pod-id": "${record.dig("kubernetes", "pod_id")}",
      "kubernetes-pod-ip": "${record.dig("kubernetes", "pod_ip")}",
      "kubernetes-container-name": "${record.dig("kubernetes", "container_name")}",
      "kubernetes-namespace-name": "${record.dig("kubernetes", "namespace_name")}",
      "kubernetes-namespace-id": "${record.dig("kubernetes", "namespace_id")}"
    }
  </record>
</filter>
```

Also I tried this (no quotes, but with braces):

```
<filter app.**>
  @type record_transformer

  renew_record true

  <record>
    severity ${record["severity"]}
    message ${record["message"]}
    logging.googleapis.com/trace ${record["trace"]}
    logging.googleapis.com/spanId ${record["spanId"]}
    logging.googleapis.com/labels {
      "kubernetes-host": ${record.dig("kubernetes", "host")},
      "kubernetes-pod-name": ${record.dig("kubernetes", "pod_name")},
      "kubernetes-pod-id": ${record.dig("kubernetes", "pod_id")},
      "kubernetes-pod-ip": ${record.dig("kubernetes", "pod_ip")},
      "kubernetes-container-name": ${record.dig("kubernetes", "container_name")},
      "kubernetes-namespace-name": ${record.dig("kubernetes", "namespace_name")},
      "kubernetes-namespace-id": ${record.dig("kubernetes", "namespace_id")}
    }
  </record>
</filter>
```

Also I tried this (no quotes and no braces):

```
<filter app.**>
  @type record_transformer

  renew_record true

  <record>
    severity ${record["severity"]}
    message ${record["message"]}
    logging.googleapis.com/trace ${record["trace"]}
    logging.googleapis.com/spanId ${record["spanId"]}
    logging.googleapis.com/labels {
      "kubernetes-host": record.dig("kubernetes", "host"),
      "kubernetes-pod-name": record.dig("kubernetes", "pod_name"),
      "kubernetes-pod-id": record.dig("kubernetes", "pod_id"),
      "kubernetes-pod-ip": record.dig("kubernetes", "pod_ip"),
      "kubernetes-container-name": record.dig("kubernetes", "container_name"),
      "kubernetes-namespace-name": record.dig("kubernetes", "namespace_name"),
      "kubernetes-namespace-id": record.dig("kubernetes", "namespace_id")
    }
  </record>
</filter>
```

But each time Fluentd failed with following error:

> /opt/bitnami/fluentd/gems/fluentd-1.12.0/lib/fluent/config/basic_parser.rb:92:in `parse_error!': got incomplete JSON hash configuration at fluentd.conf line 92,9 (Fluent::ConfigParseError)

My entire config (92th line from the error message is the last line of the config with `</match>`):

```
# Ignore fluentd own events
<match fluent.**>
  @type null
</match>

# TCP input to receive logs from
<source>
  @type forward

  bind 0.0.0.0
  port 24224
</source>

# HTTP input for the liveness and readiness probes
<source>
  @type http

  bind 0.0.0.0
  port 9880
</source>

# Throw the healthcheck to the standard output instead of forwarding it
<match fluentd.healthcheck>
  @type stdout
</match>

<filter kubernetes.var.log.containers.**.log>
  @type grep

  <regexp>
    key log
    pattern /^\[(?<logtime>[0-9T:.+-]+)\] \[(?<trace>.*?)\/(?<spanId>.*?)\] \[(?<channel>.+?)\] (?<severity>[A-Z]+): (?<message>.+)$/
  </regexp>
</filter>

<filter kubernetes.var.log.containers.**.log>
  @type parser

  key_name log

  <parse>
    @type regexp

    expression /^\[(?<logtime>[0-9T:.+-]+)\] \[(?<trace>.*?)\/(?<spanId>.*?)\] \[(?<channel>.+?)\] (?<severity>[A-Z]+): (?<message>.+)$/
    time_key logtime
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z
  </parse>
</filter>

<match kubernetes.var.log.containers.**.log>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter

  <rule>
    key channel
    pattern /^(\w+)$/
    tag app.$1
  </rule>
</match>

<filter app.**>
  @type record_transformer

  renew_record true

  <record>
    severity ${record["severity"]}
    message ${record["message"]}
    logging.googleapis.com/trace ${record["trace"]}
    logging.googleapis.com/spanId ${record["spanId"]}
    logging.googleapis.com/labels {
      "kubernetes-host": record.dig("kubernetes", "host"),
      "kubernetes-pod-name": record.dig("kubernetes", "pod_name"),
      "kubernetes-pod-id": record.dig("kubernetes", "pod_id"),
      "kubernetes-pod-ip": record.dig("kubernetes", "pod_ip"),
      "kubernetes-container-name": record.dig("kubernetes", "container_name"),
      "kubernetes-namespace-name": record.dig("kubernetes", "namespace_name"),
      "kubernetes-namespace-id": record.dig("kubernetes", "namespace_id")
    }
  </record>
</filter>

<match app.**>
  @type google_cloud

  autoformat_stackdriver_trace true

  <inject>
    time_key time
    time_type string
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
  </inject>
</match>
```

How do I define this value properly? I haven't found any examples neither of using `hash` data type (with Ruby expressions as values) and usage of `logging.googleapis.com/labels` property in Google Cloud plugin.

Comment: Can you please specify the line number (92) in that posted config?

Comment: @Azeem, updated the question with entire config. 92th line is the last line of the config with just `</match>` in it.

Comment: And, without that hash, it works properly, right? I'm assuming that you're testing the config using `--dry-run` option of fluentd.

Comment: Yeah, without `logging.googleapis.com/labels` and hash everything works well.

Comment: Just posted the tested config as an answer. It was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested with this (single quotes inside double quotes):

```
<filter app.**>
  @type record_transformer

  renew_record true

  <record>
    severity ${record["severity"]}
    message ${record["message"]}
    logging.googleapis.com/trace ${record["trace"]}
    logging.googleapis.com/spanId ${record["spanId"]}

    logging.googleapis.com/labels {
      "kubernetes-host": "${record.dig('kubernetes', 'host')}",
      "kubernetes-pod-name": "${record.dig('kubernetes', 'pod_name')}",
      "kubernetes-pod-id": "${record.dig('kubernetes', 'pod_id')}",
      "kubernetes-pod-ip": "${record.dig('kubernetes', 'pod_ip')}",
      "kubernetes-container-name": "${record.dig('kubernetes', 'container_name')}",
      "kubernetes-namespace-name": "${record.dig('kubernetes', 'namespace_name')}",
      "kubernetes-namespace-id": "${record.dig('kubernetes', 'namespace_id')}"
    }
  </record>
</filter>
```

And, with `--dry-run` (with some commented config for unavailable plugins):

```
$ fluentd -c ./fluent-hash-test.conf --dry-run
2021-01-14 17:57:13 +0500 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="./fluent-hash-test.conf"
...
2021-01-14 17:57:13 +0500 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>
  <source>
    @type http
    bind "0.0.0.0"
    port 9880
  </source>
  <filter app.**>
    @type record_transformer
    renew_record true
    <record>
      severity ${record["severity"]}
      message ${record["message"]}
      logging.googleapis.com/trace ${record["trace"]}
      logging.googleapis.com/spanId ${record["spanId"]}
      logging.googleapis.com/labels {"kubernetes-host":"${record.dig('kubernetes', 'host')}","kubernetes-pod-name":"${record.dig('kubernetes', 'pod_name')}","kubernetes-pod-id":"${record.dig('kubernetes', 'pod_id')}","kubernetes-pod-ip":"${record.dig('kubernetes', 'pod_ip')}","kubernetes-container-name":"${record.dig('kubernetes', 'container_name')}","kubernetes-namespace-name":"${record.dig('kubernetes', 'namespace_name')}","kubernetes-namespace-id":"${record.dig('kubernetes', 'namespace_id')}"}
    </record>
  </filter>
</ROOT>
2021-01-14 17:57:13 +0500 [info]: finished dry run mode
```